# ExpandableListView Opens New Activity Below

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to show the an Activity when I clicked the Group in ExpandableListview, I tried to put an intent to the onGroupExpand to open new activity and not the child lists. But when it only opens the activity. I wanna show it below when I click the Group. here is my code

```
package pack.ExpandableListtwo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

 public class ExpandableListDemo extends ExpandableListActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              
                R.layout.group_row,                         
                new String[] { "Group Item" },  
                new int[] { R.id.row_name },                        
                createChildList(),              
                R.layout.child_row,             
                new String[] {"Sub Item"},      
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i ) { // 3 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","Group Item " + i ); // the key and it's value.
        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;
}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i ) { // this -3 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
              MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     result.add( secList );
    }        
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();         
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {


        return true;
    } 

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

    }
}  
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're asking, you want to open another activity _as part of the screen_ instead of replacing the existing activity on the screen.  This is not possible in Android.  If you want to show something below your listview, read up about fragments.

Answer (score 0):

As Aleks said, it is not possible because every activity can contain only single layout though you can use some kind of bottom to top animation or using visibility to hide and show your another layout in the same xml ,that you can put below your ExpnadibleListView.